# Time complexity : Getting incorrect result

Tags: java, string, time-complexity, big-o, permutation

The following code is from the book "Cracking the coding interview". The code prints all permutations of a string.

**Question** : What is the time complexity of the code below.

```
void permutation(String str) {
    permutation(str, "");
}

private void permutation(String str, String prefix) {

    if (str.length() == 0){
        System.out.println(prefix);
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i <str.length(); i++) {
            String rem = str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i + 1);
            permutation(rem, prefix + str.charAt(i));
        }
    }
}
```

**My Understanding:**

I am able to derive the time complexity to : n * n!.

I am sure I am missing the time complexity of the blue, green and yellow nodes. But despite repeated attempts have not been clearly able to figure out the way out.

Can someone share some inputs, preferably with examples?

[image]

Comment: Is there any reason you suspect that you're getting the wrong answer?

Comment: What I had been unable to calculate were 2 things you explained very well: Sum 1: Number of Calls and Sum 2: Work Processing Strings. Even though the final result is the same, my solution was missing this piece. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're very much on the right track here, and your overall assessment (that the runtime is Θ(n · n!)) is correct! One technique we can use to derive the runtime would be to sum up, the work done at each layer in the tree. We know that

- in layer 0 (the top layer), there's 1 node processing a string of length n,
- in layer 1, there are n nodes each processing strings of length n - 1,
- in layer 2, there are n(n-1) nodes each processing strings of length n - 2,
- in layer 3, there are n(n-1)(n-2) nodes each processing strings of length n -3,
- ...
- in layer n, there are n! nodes each processing strings of length 0.

To account for the total work done here, let's assume that each recursive call does O(1) work at baseline, plus work proportional to the length of the string that it's processing. This means that we need to work out two sums to determine the total work done:

> Sum 1: Number of Calls
>
> 1 + n + n(n-1) + n(n-1)(n-2) + ... + n!

and

> Sum 2: Work Processing Strings
>
> 1 · n + n · (n-1) + n(n-1)·(n-2) + ... + n! · 0

But there's one other factor to account for - each recursive call that hits a base case prints out the string produced this way, which takes O(n) time. So that adds in a final factor of Θ(n · n!). The total work done, therefore, will be Θ(n · n!), plus the work done by all the intermediate recursive calls building up the answers.

Let's treat each of those sums individually.

### Sum 1: Number of Calls

We're dealing with this unusual sum:

> 1 + n + n(n-1) + n(n-1)(n-2) + ... + n!

The main observation we need is that

- 1 = n! / n!,
- n = n! / (n-1)!,
- n(n-1) = n! / (n-2)!
- ...
- n! = n! / (n-n)!

So, in other words, this sum is

> n! / n! + n! / (n-1)! + n! / (n-2)! + ... + n! / 0!
>
> = n!(1 / n! + 1/(n-1)! + 1/(n-2)! + ... + 1/0!)
>
> ≤ en!
>
> = Θ(n!)

Here, that last step follows from the fact that the sum

> 1/0! + 1/1! + 1/2! + 1/3! + ...

out to infinity is one of the ways of defining the number e. This means that the number of total recursive calls made here is Θ(n!).

And, intuitively, that should make sense. Each recursive call, except for recursive calls on strings of length one, makes two other recursive calls, so the recursion tree is mostly branching. And there's a nice fact about trees that says that a tree where every node is branching will not have more internal nodes than leaves. Since there are n! leaves, it's not surprising that the remaining number of nodes comes out to something that's not asymptotically bigger than n!.

### Sum 2: Work Processing Strings

This is the sum

> 1 · n + n · (n-1) + n(n-1)·(n-2) + ... + n! · 0

We can rewrite this as

> n + n(n-1) + n(n-1)(n-2) + ...

and hey! We know that sum - it's almost literally the same one we just saw. That works out to Θ(n!).

### Putting It All Together

To summarize, this recursive algorithm does

- Θ(n!) work simply due to the number of recursive calls, with each call taking some base amount of time;
- Θ(n!) work done by the recursive calls as they form and concatenate substrings; and
- Θ(n · n!) work done by the final recursive calls to print out all the permutations.

Summing this all up gives the **Θ(n · n!)** runtime that you proposed in your question.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

The time complexity will be `O(n!)`. Here is an analysis(copied from [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/heaps-algorithm-for-generating-permutations/)). It is also known as Heap's algorithm.

**Complexity Analysis:**

1. The algorithm generates `(n-1)!` permutations of the first `n-1` elements, adjoining the last element to each of these. This will generate all of the permutations that end with the last element.
2. If `n` is odd, swap the first and last element and if `n` is even, then swap the ith element (i is the counter starting from 0) and the last element and repeat the above algorithm till i is less than n.
3. In each iteration, the algorithm will produce all the permutations that end with the current last element.

Comment: The reason I don't think this is correct is : The number of final permutations alone are n! ( image above ), meaning the above analysis does not consider the time complexity of the blue, green and yellow nodes, each of which has a substring function ( which has N complexity ). Adding this missing complexity would make the final complexity  more than n! for sure.

Comment: I don't believe this answer is correct. Simply printing out all permutations of a n distinct items will take time Omega(n * n!), since there are n! permutations and it takes Omega(n) time to print each of them.

Comment: Also, I think the permutations algorithm you're referencing is a different algorithm that the recursive one that the OP is asking about.

Comment: @templatetypedef The statement `O(n!) == O(n^n)`, so by that logic `O(n*n!) == O(n^n+1) == O(n!)`

Comment: O(n!) is not the same as O(n^n). Additionally, O(n^n) and O(n^{n+1}) are different complexity classes.